# Archiving Jira tasks for the free version

Tags: task, jira, kanban

I am trying to have the option to Archive tasks in Jira (the free version) and everything that I found on the internet says that there should be an option to do that from the scheme settings of the Project.

**My question is **
Is this possible or do I have to pay to get more options and features? Another question would be, is there a way to show the Sub-tasks icon instead of the normal view? like to have it appear that from the normal view of the Kanban Board?

That is what I found on the internet:

Open Issues.

Select the issues you want to view.
Open the Tools drop-down and select the number of issues you want to perform the change on. You can perform the change on the current page or a maximum of 1000 issues. You might not have these options if you only have a few issues. Then you can only select to perform the operation on the issues you have.

Select the issues you want to archive and click Next.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the wrong documentation for the wrong type of Jira.

The ability to archive Issues is a feature of Jira DATA CENTER. You are using Jira CLOUD, which doesn't support Issue archiving. Refer to [JRACLOUD-5843](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-5843)